# Java utility method as a static or prototype

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

Would it make more sense making a utility method static or make non static with a scope of prototype?

i.e.

```
public static void setPdfVariables(String pdfFileName, boolean isDebugEnabled, ModelAndView modelAndView){
    modelAndView.addObject(PDF_FILE_NAME_KEY, pdfFileName);
    modelAndView.addObject(IS_DEBUG_ENABLED_KEY, isDebugEnabled);
}
```

Or
With a Scope of prototype

```
public void setPdfVariables(String pdfFileName, boolean isDebugEnabled, ModelAndView modelAndView){
    modelAndView.addObject(PDF_FILE_NAME_KEY, pdfFileName);
    modelAndView.addObject(IS_DEBUG_ENABLED_KEY, isDebugEnabled);
}
```

Comment: please take time to format your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you are only modifying the parameters you pass in to this method `public static void` seems fine.